# Conditions for complex integrability

Tags: integration, complex-integration

I was wondering if the Lebesgue conditions for Riemann integrability also hold for a complex path integral, and what that would mean exactly. I am assuming that $f(z)$ would have to be bounded and continuous almost everywhere along a path $\gamma(t)$, but I am wondering what are the conditions on $\gamma(t)$ itself. I've found some references say that $\gamma(t)$ has to be "smooth" on an interval $[a,b]$ (which means $C^{\infty}?$), but another reference only requiring the path to be $C^{1}$, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The path integral $$\int_\gamma f(z)\,dz$$
makes sense if $f$ is continuous and $\gamma$ is continuous with finite length, or bounded variation if you will. You can define it as the limit of sums $$\sum_{k=1}^n f\big(\gamma(t^*_k)\big)\big(\gamma(t_k)-\gamma(t_{k-1})\big)$$
with $t^*_k\in[t_{k-1},t_k]$, as the partition is refined.

An alternate take: You could think of it as a Stieltjes integral $$\int f(\gamma(t))\,d\gamma(t),$$ with the corresponding integration criteria borrowed from Stieltjes theory.

Comment: So, integrability for a path integral requires stronger conditions than in the real case (continuity everywhere on the path $\gamma$ is stronger than continuity almost everywhere).

Comment: No, I didn't say that continuity is *necessary*. But the BV restriction on the *path* is essential. I would guess, though I don't know a proof, that the integral exists in the Riemann–Stieltjes sense iff $f(\gamma(t))$ is continuous wrt $t$ almost everywhere wrt the total variation measure along the path. (When I say Riemann–Stieltjes, I refer to the Stieltjes integral as done in analogy with the Riemann integral. There is also a more powerful Lebesgue–Stieltjes theory.)

Comment: Ah - I am trying to decipher the necessary and sufficient conditions for complex integrability (esp. when it comes to continuity), similarly to what we know for the Riemann integral: bounded and a.e. continuous on [a,b], but I realize that the path now enters somehow in the conditions (which is captured by the Stieltjes integral, if I understand correctly).

Comment: do you have a reference I could consult for complex integration/integration/Stieltjes integration? (I realized these might not be in the same book)

Comment: Complex integration: Just about any book on complex analysis. However, the authors of those books aren't usually interested in minimal assumptions, since the main application is to analytic functions, and those are rather nice. Stieltjes integration: I have in mind a book that's in my office – but I am at home, and don't remember the title. I will try to remember looking it up tomorrow. There is also a chapter on Stieltjes integration in Frank E. Burk's *A Garden of Integrals* (MAA 2007, ISBN 978-0-88385-337-5). Again, it doesn't go for minimal assumptions.

Comment: I have the book by Burk's. It's interesting that people don't expose minimal conditions, because in a sense, those give the largest set of of functions that can be integrated. If you can remember the reference in your office, that would be great! Thanks in any case.

Comment: The reference I had in mind is the first chapter of Widder's *The Laplace Transform* (Princeton 1941. I have the 1972 printing, ISBN 0-691-07992-7). Still no minimal conditions, but more detail. And it reminded me of the complexity of the subject: For example, $\int_a^b f\,dg$ exists if $f$ is BV and $g$ is continuous.

Comment: But why this dearth of minimal conditions in so many references? In another venue, another guy and me have been looking for those minimal conditions, and we keep finding various conditions, but can't seem to find the definitive, minimal conditions. It's kind of surprising to me. Thanks again for the reference though :-)